# "Object Variable not set" error when setting assigning worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been regularly running a macro, and now it is not working. The part I am having trouble with is defining the worksheet as a first worksheet of a workbook, (which I have previously defined).
It's telling me wbCopy.Sheets(1) object variable not set. the last line is giving me the error.

```
Dim wbCopy As Workbook  
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet  
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Dim wsName As String
   
    Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheets("Summary").Range("C1").Value) 'Workbook we will be copying data from, our source file
    
    Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Sheets(1) 'Worksheet we will be copying data from
```

Comment: Is that workbook (`wbCopy`) already open, or does `Workbooks.Open` actually open it?

Comment: It actually opens it. It was already open, I closed it and now it works. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah `Workbooks.Open` is known to do this when the workbook is already open.

Comment: `Filename:=("C:\Test\YourFilename.xlsx")`

Comment: @NoobVB .... no. There should definitely *not* be a parenthesis after `:=`. And OP has it just fine.

Comment: my bad... mixed with Python.... :)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on from the comments - here is a function to check if a workbook is open and if not, open it then return a reference to avoid these issues:

```
Public Function GetWorkBook(ByVal sFullName As String, Optional ReadOnly As Boolean) As Workbook
    Dim sFile As String: sFile = Dir(sFullName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks(sFile)
    If GetWorkBook Is Nothing Then Set GetWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(sFullName, ReadOnly:=ReadOnly)
End Function
```